# Geometry question with congruent triangles and isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

In the diagram below $AD\equiv BC$ and $\alpha + \beta=180^{\circ}$. Find the measure of $\theta$.

[image]

I'm given a hint:

First extend $DC$ past $C$ to the point $E$ where $CE \equiv AB$, then draw $AE$ and look for congruent triangles.

So I did extend the figure and I get something like this:

[image]

Now $\Delta ADE$ ALMOST looks like an isosceles triangle which would imply $\theta = 42^{\circ}$ but I'm not sure how to justify this.

It also looks like $\Delta ACE$ and $\Delta ABC$ are congruent which would imply $\angle AEC = 42^{\circ}$ but again, I can't be sure.

Can someone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a good start. As shown in the updated diagram below, draw a line from $E$ perpendicular to $AC$, meeting it at $F$, and similarly from $B$ perpendicular to $AC$, meeting it at $G$. Also, join $B$ to $E$ and $A$ to $E$.

[image: Diagram of OP with lines EF and BG drawn perpendicular to AC, plus BE and AE added]

Note that

$$\measuredangle ACE = \measuredangle CAB = \alpha, \;\;\; \lvert CE\rvert = \lvert AB\rvert \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

We then get that $\measuredangle CEF = \measuredangle ABG$, so

$$\triangle CEF \cong \triangle ABG \;\;\to\;\; \lvert EF \rvert = \lvert BG \rvert \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Thus, $BEFG$ is a rectangle, so $BE \parallel AC$, which means $ABEC$ is an [isosceles trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid). Thus, as stated in that article, the opposite angles are supplementary, so it's also a [cyclic quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral), and therefore as the [subtended angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtended_angle) on the same side as $AC$ are equal, we get

$$\measuredangle ABC = \measuredangle AEC = 42^{\circ} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since isosceles trapezoid diagonal lengths are of equal length, then

$$\lvert AE\rvert = \lvert BC\rvert = \lvert AD\rvert \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, as you suggested, $\triangle ADE$ is an isosceles triangle, so we get from \eqref{eq3A} that

$$\theta = \measuredangle ADE = \measuredangle AED = 42^{\circ} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Comment: Thanks! I got it now :) .

Comment: @FutureMathperson You're welcome. Note I just added an updated version of your original diagram, as well as a few other details, to help make the answer a bit easier to follow.

Comment: That makes it even more clear. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quicker solution that exploits the conditions $AD = BC$ and $\alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$ in a natural way.

A common trick is to construct $F$ such that $\triangle BFC = \triangle ACD$, which is possible because $BC = AD$.
Then, the $\alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$  condition implies that $ACFB$ is a cyclic quad.
Since $AC = BF$, hence this cyclic quad is isosceles trapezoidpezoid.
Thus $42^\circ = \angle ABC = \angle BCF = \angle ADC = \theta $.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close!

For a solution using your hint and ideas that you already stated:

> 1. $ABC$ and $CEA$ are congruent triangles by SAS (by construction), which you guessed at.

> 2. Hence $AD = BC = AE$, giving us the isosceles triangle which you guessed at

> 3. Thus $\angle ADC = \angle CEA = \angle ABC = 42^\circ$